# ViewPager Not Updating Correct Detail

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, fragmentpageradapter

I have a ViewPager full of different people with work orders assigned to them. I'm trying to follow the master/detail flow with the people as the view pagers, master is the list of work orders, and the detail is the work order details.

For some reason, when I switch viewpagers, the view pager adapter updates correctly as well as the master list showing the proper work order lists. But when I click on the cardview, it doesn't update the detail container correctly. Sometimes, it updates a different detail container on another viewpage. I know the cardview in the master list is registering correctly, because I have a toast message displaying info tied to the detail.

[image: Sample Picture]

I can't seem to understand why it will occasionally update the detail fragment correctly occasionally, and then most of the times it won't and will update a detail container in another view pager.

Please let me know if I'm not supplying enough information.

PagerAdapter:

```
public class WorkOrderPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

private Context context;
private String tabTitles[];
private String employeeIds[];
private int numOfEmployees;
private Map<String, Employee> employees;

public WorkOrderPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Context cont, Map<String, Employee> allEmployees) {
    super(fm);
    context = cont;
    employees = allEmployees;

    // Construct the Tab Titles from all Employees
    employeeIds = employees.keySet().toArray(new String[employees.keySet().size()]);
    numOfEmployees = employeeIds.length;
    tabTitles = new String[numOfEmployees];

    for (int i =0; i < numOfEmployees; i++) {
        tabTitles[i] = employees.get(employeeIds[i]).getDisplayName();
    }
}

@Override
public int getCount() {return numOfEmployees;}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {

    return PageFragment.newInstance(employees.get(employeeIds[position]));
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return tabTitles[position];
}
```

}

Work Order Recycler View Adapter:

```
public class WorkOrderRVAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<WorkOrderViewHolder> {

public static final String WORK_ORDER = "workorders.workorder";
private ArrayList<WorkOrder> workOrders;
private Activity mContext;
private View.OnClickListener clickListener;

public WorkOrderRVAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<WorkOrder> works) {
    mContext = context;
    workOrders = works;

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return workOrders.size();
}

@Override
public WorkOrderViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.work_order_card_view, viewGroup, false);

    clickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            WorkOrderViewHolder holder = (WorkOrderViewHolder) v.getTag();
            int position = holder.getAdapterPosition();

            WorkOrder workOrder = workOrders.get(position);
            Toast.makeText(mContext, workOrder.getWorkOrderId(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            WorkOrderDetailFragment workFragment = new WorkOrderDetailFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putParcelable(WorkOrderRVAdapter.WORK_ORDER, workOrders.get(position));
            workFragment.setArguments(args);
            mContext.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.work_order_detail_frame, workFragment).commit();
        }
    };

    return new WorkOrderViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final WorkOrderViewHolder workOrderViewHolder, int i) {
    workOrderViewHolder.workOrderId.setText(workOrders.get(i).getWorkOrderId());
    workOrderViewHolder.workType.setText(workOrders.get(i).getWorkOrderTask());
    workOrderViewHolder.workAddress.setText(workOrders.get(i).getLocation());

    // Ternary on priority star
    workOrderViewHolder.priorityStar.setImageResource(
            (workOrders.get(i).getPriority() < 1) ?
                    R.mipmap.unselected_star : R.mipmap.selected_star);

    workOrderViewHolder.cv.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
    workOrderViewHolder.cv.setTag(workOrderViewHolder);

}

@Override
public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
}
```

}

Work Order Detail Fragment:

```
public class WorkOrderDetailFragment extends Fragment {

private WorkOrder workOrder;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (getArguments().containsKey(WorkOrderRVAdapter.WORK_ORDER)) {
        workOrder = getArguments().getParcelable(WorkOrderRVAdapter.WORK_ORDER);
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.work_order_detail, container, false);
    if (workOrder != null) {
        ((TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.work_id)).setText(workOrder.getWorkOrderId());
    }

    return rootView;
}
```

}

**EDIT**
adding page fragment

Page Fragment:

```
public class PageFragment extends Fragment{

public static final String ARG_PAGE = "ARG_PAGE";
private ArrayList<WorkOrder> workOrders;

public static PageFragment newInstance(Employee emp) {
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    if (emp != null) {
        args.putSerializable(ARG_PAGE, emp.getWorkOrders());
    } else {
        args.putSerializable(ARG_PAGE, new ArrayList<WorkOrder>());
    }
    PageFragment fragment = new PageFragment();
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // noinspection unchecked
    workOrders = (ArrayList)getArguments().getSerializable(ARG_PAGE);
    getArguments().remove(ARG_PAGE);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_page, container, false);

    RecyclerView workOrdersRV = (RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.work_order_rv);
    workOrdersRV.setHasFixedSize(true);
    StaggeredGridLayoutManager workOrdersLayoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(1, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    workOrdersRV.setLayoutManager(workOrdersLayoutManager);

    WorkOrderRVAdapter adapter = new WorkOrderRVAdapter(getActivity(), workOrders);
    workOrdersRV.setAdapter(adapter);

    return view;
}
```

}

Comment: Code for PageFragment please.

Comment: added the code for the page fragment

Comment: I think my pain point might be something to do with my fragment managing going on between my WorkOrderRVAdapter and my WorkOrderDetailFragment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be using nested fragments (`ViewPager` pages as `PageFragment` instances, where those fragments hold onto other fragments, such as `WorkOrderDetailFragment`).

If that is correct, do not use `getFragmentManager()` to update the nested fragments (e.g., the `WorkOrderDetailFragment`). Instead, [use `getChildFragmentManager()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getChildFragmentManager%28%29), called on the outer fragment (the `PageFragment`).

Personally, I avoid nested fragments outright. For example, if the detail pane (the big red square in your screenshot) is always a `WorkOrderDetailFragment`, don't use a fragment there.

Comment: I have to add, I've went and purchased Commonsware book listed on his profile and it has come in handy so many times that I've had to stop leaning on Stack Overflow for asking questions!